# How to emulate jitter WITHOUT packet reordering, using TC and NETEM?

Tags: linux, networking, delay, jitter

Apparently NETEM uses tfifo, which queues packets based on time to sent. This results in jitter causing packet reorder. For example the following line will cause packet reordering*:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: netem delay 10ms 100ms
```

[NETEM manual](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) suggests if you don't want reordering, then replace the internal queue discipline tfifo with a pure packet fifo (pfifo), and gives the following example too add lots of jitter without reordering:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: netem delay 10ms 100ms
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 pfifo limit 1000
```

But it doesn't work! Packets still get reordered! (and it looks like it's kernel dependent according to [this](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/netem/2011-April/001507.html))

So, does anyone know how to add jitter WITHOUT reordering packets?

Answer (score 1):

One hacky option is to use constant delay (no jitter) and have a loop and change the delay value in the loop.

Say you want a 50ms delay with 5ms variance. You first add the base delay:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: netem delay 50ms
```

And can the have a loop that picks a random delay between 45ms and 55ms and change the delay as below:

```
tc qdisc change dev eth0 root handle 1: netem delay 53ms
```

There are two things to keep in mind though:

1- It takes some ticks to change the delay. I found a sleep of 0.1s in the loop is reasonable. So this means your limited by the jitter frequency.

2- When you decrease the delay, new packets get queued with a smaller delay (i.e. earlier send time) than packets already in the queue, which can cause reordering! You can mitigate this by decreasing the delay in a few steps, if the decrease is significant.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Linux 4.17), I got the same ofo issue if the variance > mean. By setting the variance < mean, ofo does not happen any more. Of course you still need to use the pfifo qdisc:

```
tc qdisc add dev ethBr2   root handle 1:0    netem delay 50ms 40ms 25%
tc qdisc add dev ethBr2   parent 1:1         pfifo limit 1000
```